# Cookie values are not getting applied unless page is reloaded again

Tags: php, html, cookies

On the site i am working on, i have the option to customise the site when user chooses a color by changing the stylesheets.

Say, i have 5 colors. If i click on a color, the stylesheet name is stored in a hidden input tag. Once the 'Enter' button is clicked, the value in hidden tag is stored in a cookie. Accordingly, the stylesheet file changes in  tag. The code for it is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['style'])){
echo $_COOKIE['style'];}
else{
echo 'style.css';}?>"/>
```

But the style is applied only after reloading every page though the cookie has been set.

What do i do to apply the style in the cookie once the page is loaded? I mean there should be no need to reload it again to get the style applied.

**NOTE:** The cookies are created in javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting cookie with js but reading it with php, so you need to refresh since php is serverside. When you set cookie reload the page and you should see changes

Comment: so is there a way to change the href in link tag by using the cookie set in javascipt? how to retrieve the cookie in link tag without using php?

Comment: link you sent seems to help. Working on it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

there is difference between server side and client side ....  php execute server side so you need to refreash page so you can get cookie .you are doing by JavaScript which is client side

Comment: so is there a way to change the href in link tag by using the cookie set in javascipt? how to retrieve the cookie in link tag without using php?

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar  either reload the page or ajax request ..... than change it by ..jquery(javascript) ...with ajax and jquery you can do both  set cookie and change link without reloading page and next time when page reload you will get stored in cookie